# Launch Modal on Page_Load with JavaScript doesn't work - ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to launch a modal on the Load_Page on my ASP.NET C# application and doesn't work. This is the JavaScript code to launch it:

```
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "none", "<script>$('#miModal').modal('show');</script>", false);
```

The thing is, I use the same modal with the same code in one button, and it works fine. What could be the problem? There is something working different with the Page_Load event??

**I used UpdatePanel, ContentTemplate in the button** and ScriptManager in the .aspx file. Maybe this matters.

Comment: Do you get an error in your JavaScript console window in the browser? That's incredibly important to mention if you're having an issue running JavaScript. In this case, you'll probably get some error about jQuery not existing. But really for me, this begs the question: why are you doing this from the Page_Load? Why aren't you doing this in the normal page markup?

Comment: @mason I have never used the console windows but here is the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at MyPage.aspx:100` . And the line 100 is part of the code to launch the modal: `<script>$('#miModal').modal('show');</script>` . And well, I want to launch the modal in the pageload because is a application form with some textbox to fill.

Comment: `$` is the jQuery operator. It's exactly like I said, you're executing this JavaScript before the jQuery library is loaded (or you're not loading jQuery at all). And your reasoning doesn't make sense for why you must do this from Page_Load in C#. Whether it has an application form or not, you could still embed this script in the markup for the page instead of the code behind. That would give you more control over the loading/execution order of your JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your jquery library already loaded.
Also, there is a change the control was not load to the DOM yet, so use:

```
<script>$( document ).ready(function() {$('#miModal').modal('show');});</script>
```